# How does property lookups after calling super() in subclass actually work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I've a simple example from MDN.

```
class Animal { 


 constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name); // call the super class constructor and pass in the name parameter
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' barks.');
  }
}

let d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // Mitzie barks.
```

Now, in subclass `Dog` how does `this.name` works under the hood. Since `this` refers to `Dog` class instance  and name is not something which exists on Dog instance. So to access that we use super call which invokes parent's constructor. I get that it looks up.

But can someone please explain via the prototype mechanism (I'm comfortable in understanding the prototype lookup and chaining mechanism).

I'm sure deep down  it will boil down to that but not clear about intermediate steps in between. Thanks!

Comment: It could be using `.bind()/.call()/.apply()` under the hood.

Comment: Umm...hard to imagine. Can you elaborate please! More visually maybe

Comment: Or maybe provide a resource to read.

Comment: Are you asking about `this.name` in the `Dog.prototype.speak` method, or about the `super` call in the `Dog` constructor function?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ this link could help you. paste your code and see the es5 version of it to understand or you might look into some compilers like tsc/babel etc.

Comment: @Bergi Hey Dude. I was asking about the `this.name` inside `speak` method. I wasn't able to get the fact that by calling `super(name)` we have already added the name property to instantiated object. Therefore `this.name` inside `speak` works. @CertainPerformance helps. I hope, I wrote it correctly

Comment: @Jai I should have done this myself i.e. running babel to look under it. _super.call(this, name) and light bulbs. Was I lazy?  Thanks for pointing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I wanted to ask was under the hood. So, here's the answer based on @Jai's pointer in comments that I was looking for.

I ran the class based code through [es5compiler](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) or any compiler and got this conversion

```
var Dog = /** @class */ (function (_super) {

  __extends(Dog, _super);
    function Dog(name) {
        return _super.call(this, name) || this;
    }
    Dog.prototype.speak = function () {
        console.log(this.name + ' barks.');
    };
    return Dog;
}(Animal));
```

So basically

`return _super.call(this, name)` inside Dog function explains the confusion of `this` reference inside `speak` method of class Dog. It changes the context through `call()`

Answer (score 3):

> this refers to Dog class

No, `this` refers to the instantiated object. The instantiated object has an internal prototype of `Dog.prototype`, and `Dog.prototype` has an internal prototype of `Animal.prototype`.

Since `this` refers directly to the instantiated object (in *both* constructors, and in all of the methods),

```
this.name = name;
```

puts the `name` property *directly on that object*, so it's completely fine to reference `d.name`, or, inside one of the methods, `this.name`:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name); // call the super class constructor and pass in the name parameter
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' barks.');
  }
}

const d = new Dog('Mitzie');

const dProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(d);
const secondProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(dProto);
console.log(dProto === Dog.prototype);
console.log(secondProto === Animal.prototype);

console.log(d.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

Comment: `this` refers to instance ofcourse. That was my bad at writing. Anyway, are you trying to say that when `super(name)` call happens, it copies the `name` property to that object ( instance of Dog) instead of looking up?

Comment: And please edit your answer as this was not intended to based on my mistake of  writing `this` to Dog class instead of instance. Defeats the purpose of actual ask. Apologies for same

Comment: No, nothing gets copied - when `super()` happens, the `Animal`'s constructor is called, with `this` within `Animal`'s constructor referring to the instantiated object.

Comment: An object doesn't really care what its internal prototype is (here, whether it's Dog or Animal), but either way, the `.name` property is not on any of the prototypes, but on the object itself.

Comment: Umm...I was overthinking about linkage.